# firebase add user to realtime database upon sign up (javascript)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'd need to create a users main node, that will have as child users id created upon sign up, as well as child elements dynamically populated later on (empty for now).

so my db would look like:

```
- users
     - uid
        - lists
            - list name
                - content
     - uid
     - uid
     ...
```

I'm still at the beginning and for now i'm trying to put the user id inside `- users` but doesn't work, the code (**EDITED**):

```
var refUsers = database.ref('users');

// Add sign up event
btnSignup.addEventListener('click', e => {
  // to do: check for real email
  const email = txtEmail.value;
  const pass = txtPassword.value;
  const auth = firebase.auth();
  // Sign in
  auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass)
  .then(function success(userData){
    var uid = userData.uid;
    refUsers.push(uid);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  alert('Error: ' + errorMessage);
  });
});
```

I also didn't understand if i should manually or programmatically create the main `- users` node inside the database, how (since it asks me for a value too) so for now i didn't create it at all, the documentation lack of many stuff imo.

Comment: What doesn't work about that list code you added? Does it go into the `then()` block? If not, does it go into the `catch()` block? Is anything showing in the JavaScript console of your browser?

Answer (score 3):

The functionality you're describing can be achieved using [Firebase Authentication Triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events).

ie.

```
const database = firebase.database()
const createUser = user => database.ref().child(`User/${user.uid}`).set(user)
exports.createUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate(createUser)
```

Comment: I'm using realtime database, not cloud database, does it work anyway? it's throwing me the error exports is not defined